# Tabs doesn't show

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-tabs, android-sdk-tools

I want to add tab in myActivity and when I click on some tabs Fragment is created and added.But now when I clicked tab nothing happened.
TabsActivity:

```
public class TabsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    Fragment directFragmentTab = new Direct();
    Fragment adventuresFragmentTab = new AdventuresFragment();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabs_activity);


        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));

        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, tabLayout.getTabCount())
                 {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }


    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Direct tab1 = new Direct();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                AdventuresFragment tab2 = new AdventuresFragment();
                return tab2;


            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

What I did wrong?Code compile without error but something in logic I was missed.

Comment: Not sure what's going on there, but it doesn't look right. The most simple way is to use setupWithViewPager(), take a look here: https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout

Comment: check             public int getCount() {
                return 0;
            }  in viewpager adapter. it should return the count

Comment: it return a count
public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not override methods from `ViewPagerAdapter` further. Just do

```
final ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, tabLayout.getTabCount());
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this** I am Using The **same Code**

```
 final ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, tabLayout.getTabCount())
             {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return false;
        }
    };
```

**Replace With**

```
final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
```

**Edit Your Code Like This**

```
   TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
```